# Need Updated StickerView with auto face detect functionality

Tags: java, android, github

I have tried to find out a new updated `Stickerview` library but no updated library available on GitHub.

- https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView
- https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView

All the Above library not working well.

Functionality Needed:

1. Auto Face detects and applies the sticker on it very well.
2. Multiple stickers can add/replace at a time.

Please suggests **how to look for** a good library for `Stickerview`.
(This is not a request for finding a tool)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the "Network" section of those two repositories:

- https://github.com/kencheung4/android-StickerView/network
- https://github.com/nimengbo/StickerView/network

You will see the forks created from said repositories, and the newer commits done in those forks.

That way, you might find the one fork which include the fixes you want.

For example: [`usmanrana07/android-StickerView`](https://github.com/usmanrana07/android-StickerView/commit/f1bd4d79850fb4d7b53a88ae70c76c09e4b7d014) includes:

> ### Added 'controlFrameVisibility' method
>
> The controller frame should hide after particular time of `ACTION_UP` even because if user wants to take screenshot then those icons also remain visible in picture.
> I have added pieces of code which will hide the controller frame after 2 seconds of action completion and it would be visible again on touch to the view.

And [`yongjhih/StickerView`](https://github.com/yongjhih/StickerView/commit/28f08970be2b41e4ec90834996164fe3fa0b2f32) adds a `StickerManager` for simpler application, which could be of interest in your case.

There might not be the exact features you are looking for, but the "Network" section is a good way to assess if said features were already coded, or if you need to implement them.

Comment: I have tried all but not updated and still have some bugs in those libraries. Thank you for your suggestions and help.

Comment: @AnandSavjani Again, why the downvote? I was trying to show how you can look for a better alternative, not to point to a better alternative.

Comment: It is not a valid answer for me.

Comment: @AnandSavjani It is: asking for a tool is not a good fit on Stack Overflow. Asking for a way to find a good tool is.